# Text wrapping is terrible in Sublime Text--or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

When I attempt to wrap text (and is there not an automatic wrap at edge of window feature??) it totally screws up the other lines of text above and below it.
[image: before]

[image: after]

What's the deal?

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? And there is an auto wrap, but by default it doesn't apply to text. Add the following to your user settings to have it wrap regardless of the type of text. `"word_wrap": true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have the word wrap column set to a hard number, but do not have it enabled.

You can toggle it by clicking

```
View > Word Wrap
```

or
In the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) type `Word Wrap: Toggle`

If you want it to auto-wrap at the edge of the window click:

> View > Word Wrap Column > Automatic